# Feign Client bad request response body

Tags: spring-boot, feign, 400-bad-request

I`m using microservices , so i have 2 microservices . First one "BFF" is for communication between front-end and other service "data-register". For request from BFF to other service i use Feign Client. I want when I do a validation in "data-register" and there is a problem to return a bad request and custom object with field errorCode.

```
@PostMapping("/save")
public ResponseEntity<?> save(
        @RequestBody DTO dto) {
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(ErrorCode.builder().code("2313").build());
}
```

When I receive in the BFF  bad request I want to forward the same to the front-end and accordingly there I have a logic that takes this code("2313") again like BAD_REQUEST and visualizes it to the user custom message. But I don't know how to get body of bad request response  (my custom object) I'm returning.

```
@PostMapping("/save")
public <T> ResponseEntity<?> saveFinancialStabilityDoc(@RequestBody T dto) {
    Response response = feignClient.save(dto);
    if (response.status() == 400) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(response.body());
    }
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(response.body());
}
```